# Pass value of image List view to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

```
        Integer[] leftItems = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2, R.drawable.ic_3, R.drawable.ic_4, R.drawable.ic_5};
        Integer[] rightItems = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_6, R.drawable.ic_7, R.drawable.ic_8, R.drawable.ic_9, R.drawable.ic_10};

        leftAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.item, leftItems);
        rightAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.item, rightItems);
        listViewLeft.setAdapter(leftAdapter);
        listViewRight.setAdapter(rightAdapter);

        leftViewsHeights = new int[leftItems.length];
        rightViewsHeights = new int[rightItems.length];
```

For leftlist view onclick i am using below code

```
listViewLeft.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Integer name = (Integer) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Intent Courses = new Intent(ItemsActivity.this, ViewMyImage.class);
            Courses.putExtra("position",arg2);
            Courses.putExtra("name",name.toString());
            startActivity(Courses);

        }

    });
```

In ViewMyImage.java i am using this code to get values

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**I want value of images ic_X  that i can show again image.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it using `getResources().getIdentifier` to find drawable from string name as:

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
int drawableid = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_"+value , 
                                                 "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawableimg = getResources().getDrawable(drawableid);
```

now use `drawableimg` for setting ImageView background Image using `ImageView.setImageDrawable`

and send way is pass Drawable id instead if position from previous Activity to `ViewMyImage` Activity using `Courses.putExtra("position",leftItems[arg2])`. in second Activity you can pass  value to `setImageDrawable` id directly

Comment: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ListView